# How do you make Git ignore spaces and tabs?

Tags: git, diff, indentation

I have a small scripting project that consists of five different source files in one directory called "Droid XX-XX-XX". Each time I created a new backup copy of the source directory, I put the date in the X's. So there are about 15 different versions from different dates. I want to add each of these to my bare new Git repository starting from the earliest.

However I have run into several problems.

1. One problem is that some of the files use tabs for indentation, while others use spaces -- but Git treats a whole line as different even when the only difference is the tab vs. space issue. How can I make Git ignore indentation formatting?
2. Another problem is that some filenames would have no spaces while others had spaces between the words -- but Git treats them as different files. Worse, sometimes the filename was changed to something different (like "PatrolPlan" changed to just "Patrol") for no real reason. When I'm adding a new set of files, how can I tell Git that even though the filename is different, it's really just a new version of a certain older file? Or better yet, can I set it to auto-detect when this happens?
3. The last problem is that at certain points during development, we merged two source files into one, or split one into two -- but Git doesn't automatically detect the similarities and deduce what happened. How can I tell Git what happened? Or better yet, how can I set it to auto-detect when two source files were combined or when one was split up?

I realize questions (2) and (3) are highly related. Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Are you trying to copy version by version (from oldest to newest) in to the git directory and committing? Number 2 can be easily solved if that is the case. You just `git mv` the files that changed their name and then copy from the new version over them. Same thing with number 3 and I believe `git` would automatically figure out what happened to the code.

Comment: I must disagree with "changed ... for no real reason". Everything has a reason. It would be ok if it was "no reasonably controllable reason", e.g. another team that refuses to make your life easier, or some 3rd-party software that is acting obtusely.

Comment: No it really was for no real reason... I know because I did it myself, and at the time I did it, I even tought, "I have no real reason for doing this."

Comment: @CommaToast I'm confused. So if another team member asked you, "why are you renaming that file?" How would you answer? I'd be surprised if you would say, "I have none; just accept it." I think one acceptable reason would be, the new name is more descriptive.

Comment: Kelvin, I'm confused. You keep mentioning a "team" -- what are you talking about? There is no team.

Comment: @CommaToast Don't take "team" too literally :) . Imagine you cloned yourself and had to explain it to your clone. Sometimes having a debate with yourself helps in writing more maintainable code.

Comment: @Kelvin I see what you're saying. But in this particular case, I just kinda felt like renaming a file. It was 10 years ago when I was a noob developer and didn't know what I was really doing, or that renaming a file had the possibility of ever actually mattering. But it matters in git, even though it shouldn't.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's sounding like you need more control and standardization of the development process. The one who commits changes should be the same person who modifies the files. Or at least the committer should know exactly what changed.

Examine carefully the output of `git diff`, and use the `-w` flag to ignore spaces. There's also options to show differences within a line. See *Diffs within a line* below.

Note that you won't be able to tell git to skip the space changes when committing. I suggest using GitX (I prefer the "brotherbard" fork), which allows you to interactively discard hunks before committing.

Use descriptive messages when committing. For example, if a file was split, say so. Make your commits small. If you find yourself writing long commit messages, break up the commit into smaller parts. That way when you examine the logs a long time later, it will make more sense what changed.

**Diffs within a line**

Git has some ability to show "word" differences in a single line. The simplest way is to just use `git diff --color-words`.

However, I like customizing the meaning of a "word" using the `diff.wordRegex` config. I also like the `plain` word-diff format because it more clearly shows where the differences are (inserts brackets around the changes in addition to using color).

Command:

```
git diff --word-diff=plain
```

along with this in my config:

```
[diff]
        wordRegex = [[:alnum:]_]+|[^[:alnum:]_[:space:]]+
```

This regex treats these as "words":

- consecutive strings of alphanumerics and underscores
- consecutive strings of non-alphanumerics, non-underscores, and non-spaces (good for detecting operators)

You must have a recent version of `git` to use `wordRegex`. See your `git-config` man page to see if the option is listed.

**UPDATE**

If you use `git mv` to rename a file (which is preferable to using another tool or the OS to rename), you can see git detecting the rename. I highly recommend committing a rename independently of any edits to the contents of the file. That's because git doesn't actually store the fact that you renamed - it uses a heuristic based on how much the file has changed to guess whether it was the same file. The less you change it during the rename-commit, the better.

If you did change the file contents slightly, you can use `-C` param to `git diff` and `git log` to try harder to detect copies and renames. Add a percentage (e.g. `-C75%`) to make git more lenient about differences. The percent represents how similar the contents have to be to be considered a match.

Comment: Thanks... when I get home, I will try the -w flag.

Comment: I was already using -w (SourceTree's "Ignore Whitespace" option), which successfully ignores hunks only when they are relatively close to each other in line number position -- but if a large new hunk is in between two sections that are identical other than whitespace, then -w fails to ignore the difference. However if I simply open the working copy in BBEdit, and replace all space-groups with \t tabs, then save the file, and do the same thing with the subsequent version, THEN paste the contents of the new version into the working copy, NOW it will successfully ignore all whitespace differences

Comment: Better use ...`_[:space:]]+` instead of ...`_ ]+` or it will show all line endings if the file was changed from windows/linux line endings

Comment: I find Atlassian SourceTree (a GUI client for Git) a MUCH better way to handle all of this than anything on the command line. The only flaw is that you cannot filter hunks by regex, but then you can't do that efficiently on the command line either.

Comment: Also... this was a matter of going back to a project that I did BEFORE I ever knew about git, and was just using copies of folders to track versions, and then adding it into git retroactively so that there would be some history of its progress and changes. Just FYI.

Comment: @CommaToast Since posting this answer, I've started using SourceTree as well. But for certain things, it's hard to beat command line. I totally get that not everyone has the desire or time to learn the tricks (I probably know < 5%), but sometimes it pays off.

Comment: @Kelvin yes I agree. I still use the Git command line for certain things, like git diff --stat etc.

Answer (score 4):

Now that I know a lot more about Git, I can answer my own questions.

1. It would be better to do a global search-replace using regex to standardize the whitespace between all the files across the different versions of the project, so that when they are sequentially committed, the whitespaces changes won't need commits. That being said, Atlassian SourceTree's diff tool allows you to hide whitespace changes, so at least you won't see those.
2. The key to deal with filename changes is to make a commit where only the file's name changes (don't stage any other changes). Then make a commit where its contents change. That way, normal diff tools that don't do a ton of heuristics and deep digging can make sense out of what has happened. The problem is that if too much changes about a file, like the name AND a lot of the contents, then most diff tools will treat it as a summary deletion and new file. (as mentioned in the correct answer)
3. This is a tougher one, there's no really good way around it. If you split up a file into two, or merge two, it will just be ugly in the diff. Try not to make lots of changes at the same time as doing the split, so that the split will be one thing, and subsequent changes will be another.

Answer (score 2):

1. You won't be able to make git ignore tabs/spaces as git creates a hash of each file and if the hash is different the file is considered different.
2. Git treats trees (directories) the same as files; if their content changes then they are different tree's.

I don't think these changes are anything to worry about however; they happen during any development.  I think the best approach for you is to *replay* your development using git.  In other words start with your initial version and then make the necessary changes (as you did originally) and git will remember what you are doing.

Optional: If you want to record the date/time of the changes to be roughly those originally made, then you can use the `--date` command line option to `git commit` to tell git when these changes were made.

Comment: Well I have been replaying the development, by opening the files, selecting all, copying, then pasting the contents into the working copy. But lets say in the one I paste in, there was spaces instead of tabs -- Git would show that whole line as different, even though to the naked eye, it looks exactly the same.

Comment: Yeah - the file is different - even the character count is different.  You might be able to make git ignore spaces when doing a `diff` but it will always consider the file different due to different space characters.

Comment: I was really looking for a way NOT to have to manually replace the spaces with tabs prior to pasting the new file contents into the old file and saving (see my long comment on Kelvin's answer). That's the only way I've found so far to get a proper looking diff that reliably ignores whitespace. I "Show Invisibles" and "Show Spaces" in BBEdit to see the buggers, then it's obvious what to find and replace to standardize the two files' whitespace areas and saving PRIOR to pasting the new version over the old version's text. I don't feel like I should have to do this... -w isn't very robust...